# tvOS: UITabBarController unusual title appearing

Tags: objective-c, tvos

I'm implementing a simple UITabBar with 3 items using the code snippet below:

```
- (void)setupTabBar
{
    CamerasViewController *camerasViewController = [[CamerasViewController alloc] init];
    camerasViewController.title = @"Cameras";
    UINavigationController *camerasNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:camerasViewController];
    _camerasNavigationController = camerasNavigationController;


    DeliveriesViewController *deliveriesViewController = [[DeliveriesViewController alloc] init];
    deliveriesViewController.title = @"Deliveries";
    UINavigationController *deliveriesNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:deliveriesViewController];
    _deliveriesNavigationController = deliveriesNavigationController;

    LogoutViewController *logoutViewController = [[LogoutViewController alloc] init];
    logoutViewController.title = @"Logout";
    UINavigationController *logoutNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:logoutViewController];
    _logoutNavigationController = logoutNavigationController;

    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                                        NSFontAttributeName: [Constants lightFontOfSize:[Constants menuBarHeight] * 0.29]
                                                        }
                                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.tabBar.backgroundColor = [Constants goldColor];
    self.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.viewControllers = @[
                             _camerasNavigationController,
                             _deliveriesNavigationController,
                             _logoutNavigationController
                             ];

    self.tabBar.setNeedsFocusUpdate;
}
```

When rendered, I see the UITabBar rendered correctly. However, when I swipe down on the remote to focus on the view (i.e. hiding the UITabBar) I'm noticing the view titles appear in an unformatted font as shown in the 2 screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Removing the lines .title=@"view-title-string" in the code above clears this, but then I lose the titles in the TabBar.

Does anyone have recommendations on how to get rid of this title? I also tried running the following snippet on each of the 3 UIViewControllers but with no luck:

```
for (UIView *v in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        [v removeFromSuperView];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The title you're seeing there may be from the navigation controller's `UINavigationBar`. Right now your view controller hierarchy looks like this:

```
 Tab bar controller
   Cameras navigation controller
      Cameras view controller
   Deliveries navigation controller
      Deliveries view controller
   Logout navigation controller
      Logout view controller
```

But I think what you actually want is for there to be a single `UINavigationController` that contains everything else, like this:

```
Navigation controller
  Tab bar controller
    Cameras view controller
    Deliveries view controller
    Logout view controller
```

That way, the tab bar controller will use the titles of it's children to create it's buttons, but since the tab bar controller *itself* doesn't have a title, the navigation controller won't try to create a navigation bar for it.

Comment: Removing the UINavigationController under each UITabBar did indeed solve the problem. Thank you!